# ionic 2 timer causes crash in app class

Tags: ionic2

I am in an ionic 2 MyApp class, and I want to show one screen for 3 seconds then switch to another.
I get a this.nav.parent is null error.
I am trying two types of timers and neither work.
I am using tabs, and want it to go to the first tab page by the way.

```
gotoFirstPage()
{
    //these two lines work fine
    //this.nav.setRoot( TabsPage );
    //this.nav.parent.select(1); //this.nav.parent is not null here

    setTimeout((function()
    {
        this.nav.setRoot( TabsPage );
        this.nav.parent.select(1);  //this.nav.parent is null
    }.bind(this)),3000);

    let timer = Observable.timer(3000, 86400000);
   timer.subscribe(t => {
       this.nav.setRoot( TabsPage );
       this.nav.parent.select(1); //this.nav.parent is null
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a fat-arrow `=>`instead of binding this:

```
setTimeout(() =>
{
    this.nav.setRoot( TabsPage );
    this.nav.parent.select(1);  //this.nav.parent is null
},3000);
```

If that doesn't work, then your nav object in `this` is null, so the problem is not the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this.nav.parent is null but I found a better way to switch tab pages:

```
this.nav.setRoot( TabsPage, { tabIndex: 1 } );
```